# Uncompress tar.gz file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, gzip, tar

With the usage of wget command line I got a tar.gz file. I downloaded it in the root@raspberrypi. Is there any way to uncompress it in the /usr/src folder?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Use `-C` option of tar:

```
tar zxvf <yourfile>.tar.gz -C /usr/src/
```

and then, the content of the tar should be in:

```
/usr/src/<yourfile>
```

Comment: -z : filter the archive through gzip • 
-x : extract files from an archive • 
-v : verbosely list files processed • 
-f : use archive file or device F (default "-", meaning stdin/stdout)
 • See http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/tar1.html

Answer (score 25):

Try this:

```
tar -zxvf file.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 13):

```
gunzip <filename>
```

then

```
tar -xvf <tar-file-name>
```